# YouTube API - User account closed

Tags: api, youtube, channel

I would like to ask why following channels are not available via API.

http://www.youtube.com/visalus
http://www.youtube.com/user/visalus

http://www.youtube.com/etisalat
http://www.youtube.com/user/etisalat

Channels (Visalus, Etisalat) upper are available on 2 different urls. Hovewer, when I try to put following request on API:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/users/visalus?alt=json&v=2
```

It ends with following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <error>
    <domain>GData</domain>
    <code>ServiceForbiddenException</code>
    <internalReason>User account closed</internalReason>
  </error>
</errors>
```

And my questions is why this error? These channels apparently exists and they have videos. Or am I asking bad API endpoint?

Thank you for any help

R.

Answer (score 2):

When I visit those YouTube URL's they give me the same error "User account closed" in my browser.
Are you sure those are active accounts because I can't find them?
Because I think that's the problem why you can't get the info..

**EDIT:** The following account does exist:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/users/visalusvideo?alt=json&v=2

Comment: I see,

you are right - http://www.youtube.com/visalus and http://www.youtube.com/etisalat - those links works fine. The others ones not.

But, am I able to find that visalus is not visalus but visalusvideo? I mean some kind of redirect from API.

Thank you very much for you answer.